# How to copy tuples from a DB to another

Tags: postgresql, export

I think I got a really easy problem, but let's see what you say.

I created in a new DB with new tables called db2. And a filled DB called db1.

So now I want to import the tuples von db1 into db2. My idea was the following:

```
INSERT INTO "Posts" (SELECT * FROM de1.posts);
```

> ERROR: References to other databases offers are not implemented

Then I tried to add in the beginning:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('dbname=db1');
dblink_connect
```

But this leads to a syntax error.

Comment: People here at least need the version of PostgreSQL you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like shown below. Please see this example:

```
INSERT INTO t2 select * from 
dblink('host=1.2.3.4
  user=*****
  password=******
  dbname=D1', 'select * t1') tt(
    id int,
 col_1 character varying,
 col_2 character varying,
 col_3 int,
 col_4 varchar 
  );
```

Comment: what is col_1 and so on for?